# Winter Hats Are Coming Soon!

Tags: discussion

We'll do this again, as we've done in previous years.

> **The Details**
>
> This year's event will start on 14 December 2015 and run up to and
>   including 03 January 2016. Users will be able to see all the hats
>   they've earned on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com. That site
>   will also have an FAQ to explain how things work.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
>   available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
>   will go back into storage.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
>   the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.